# Trouble Decoding Uint8Array from React QR Scanner into Actual Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working with the `react-qr-reader` package for scanning QR codes in my React application. However, I'm encountering difficulties in converting the returned `Uint8Array` object into its actual value. I've attempted several methods to decode the Uint8 value into a readable string, but none seem to be successful.

Here's the code I've been using for the conversion:

```js
const encoding = 'utf-8';
const uint8Array = [
  65, 85, 118, 247, 38, 198, 66, 5, 102, 86, 37, 70, 247, 34, 4, 22, 151, 38,
  198, 150, 230, 87, 48, 236, 17, 236, 17, 236, 17, 236, 17, 236, 17, 236,
];
 try {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder(encoding);
    const decodedString = decoder.decode(uint8Array);
    console.log(decodedString);
  } catch {
    console.log("An error occurred while decoding with encoding:", encoding);
  }
```

Regardless of the encoding used (utf-8 or otherwise), the decoded string appears garbled, like so: `AUv�&�BfV7F�"�&Ɩ�W0������`.

I'm unsure whether this issue is related to the `react-qr-reader` package itself or if there's a problem with my decoding approach. Can anyone offer insights or suggest a solution to this problem?